# Java Install for IPMI on OSX

Tags: java, macos, macos-sonoma, ipmi

need your help on what is probably an easy thing but for me it has gotten the better of me. I want to access my IPMI network devices from my MacBook Pro M3 Max but unable to figure out what I need to install to get it to work like it should.

Can anyone out there help walk me through what I need to download, how to install, and how to get connected to my IMPI devices?

Currently running Sonoma 14.2 on the MacBook.

I have tried installing JDK's, Java, and setting Home Paths according to different videos/posts but either I am doing something wrong or the directions for Sonoma might be different.

Comment: https://sdkman.io/

Comment: Better than asking for another general instruction, please [edit] your question and add: What did exactly did you do so far? What errors etc. have you run into? Where are you stuck now?

Answer (score 0):

i can provide u a solution for installing.
Try out brew for mac its a package management system for MacOS.

https://brew.sh/

open the terminal (Press cmd+space and search for terminal)

and run `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh`

after installing brew on your system u just can use
brew search for the apps that u need. If you find it u can use
brew install to install and that should be it.

I hope i could help you :)

Comment: Okay so I have brew installed  per your instructions and I did the install for Java and used this command [brew install java] and if I run the command [brew install java] to check the java version I get this output.                                                                    
java version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17  / Java(TMSE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)  /. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing).                If I try to run my IPMI shortcut I get this error still...“launch.jnlp” cannot be opened because it is from an unidentified developer.

Comment: If you get the macOS message "..unidentified developer..", go to macOS Settings > Security & Privacy, there should be a message telling you the same and a button "Allow anyways". Then run again what was blocked.